# Disable moving in an iPhone web application but leave scrolling?

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, scroll

To disable native tochemove event usually one want to use:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

But what if want to prevent moving the window (ot of the borders of the screen) but leave the capabilities for scrolling the content of the page?

Answer (score 1):

With UIWebView following code might help you-

```
 UIWebView *webView = ...
//set zoom
UIScrollView *scrollView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[scrollView setZoomScale:0.0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm using phone gap to pack my web application, I probably don't have access to WebView

Comment: You absolutely do have access to the web view.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR might be using PhoneGap Build. I use PhoneGap Build to compile apps but don't have the time or know-how to edit some line of Objective-C _somewhere_ - for build users, that'd also require setting up that platform's environment and building that app independently of the rest.